# How to resume a stuck code analysis in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I recently noticed a behaviour, that the default code analysis does not finish anymore in one of my android projects, in particular in kotlin files - unfortunately without an error message. With a stuck analysis I am not able to identify errors in my code anymore and basic stuff like autocompletion does not work, which makes it unable to work.

In the top right corner of the opened file I constantly get `Analyzing...`

[image: analyzing]

I already tried restarting Android Studio, invalidating its cache, deleting and cloning my project again, rebooting and deleting all kind of gradle and Android Studio cache files but without success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally got it working again with the help of the `idea.log` file, which can be found via `Help > Show Log in Explorer` in Android Studio.

The log stated an `Exception while analyzing expression` at different locations in my files, caused by `java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method org/jetbrains/kotlin/builtins/KotlinBuiltIns.getBuiltInClassByFqName must not return null`.

Since it looked like a Kotlin related issue, I upgraded `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` in my `build.gradle` from 1.4.10 to 1.5.10 and it worked instantly again. I hope the info helps anyone!

Comment: The issue has been reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18912

Comment: Changing from 1.4.21 to 1.5.0 worked for me.

Comment: Upgrading `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` from 1.4.21 to 1.5.0 worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please remove butterknife plugin in Settings-> Plugin. It is worked for me in java files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Fixed! As me installing plugins for no sake, just for fun, I got the error. But now seems working by my side. I can see yellow and red bulb notifications as usual, but this time almost everywhere I see yellow highlighted texts in my Java codes. Top-right corner's Analysing.. text has gone, and working.